# Calling class method inside for loop

Tags: python

**I could not understand why this code run more number of times**

```
class demo:
    def first(self):
        self.i = 10
        print(f'first : {self.i}')
    def second(self):
        self.j = 20
        print(f'second : {self.j}')
    def third(self):
        self.k = 30
        print(f'third : {self.k}')

        for i in range(1):
            self.first()
            self.second()
            self.third()

d = demo()
d.first()
d.second()
d.third()
```

- This code reached its **maximum limit**
- Please explain why **for loop has not ended within its range.**
- How to avoid this error...?
- The error that, I got.

  ```
    RecursionError        Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-20-6755f27f25e3> in <module>
         23 d.first()
         24 d.second()
    ---> 25 d.third()

   <ipython-input-20-6755f27f25e3> in third(self)
         16         self.first()
         17         self.second()
    ---> 18         self.third()
         19 
         20 

   ... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

    <ipython-input-20-6755f27f25e3> in third(self)
         16         self.first()
         17         self.second()
    ---> 18         self.third()
         19 
         20 

    RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
  ```

Comment: indentation. i don't think you want the `for` loop within the method `third()` so reduce the indentation. whitespace is critically important in Python.

Comment: Third calls third which is calling third that calls third…

Answer (score 1):

Because the for loop never ends.

Think about it, before ending the for loop (which is expected to run just once) it has to complete the call to `third()` function. But the `third()` function calls itself (please note) just once, and this is enough to throw the interpreter in a never-ending cycle of calling itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `third` function is basically the same as this:

```
def third():
    for i in range(1):
        third()
```

Since the loop runs *only once* (because `range(1)` contains only one element `0`), this further simplifies to:

```
def third():
    third()
```

What happens when a function calls itself again and again and *never stops* (each call to `third` *always* calls `third`)? A stack overflow, or `RecursionError` in Python parlance.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to include "**init**" method inside the class.
An also you should put for loop which will call other methods in another method such as "start"

```
class demo:
    
    def __init__(self ) : 
        self.start()

    
    def first(self):
        self.i = 10
        print(f'first : {self.i}')
    def second(self):
        self.j = 20
        print(f'second : {self.j}')
    def third(self):
        self.k = 30
        print(f'third : {self.k}')
        
    def start(self ) : 
        for i in range(1):
            self.first()
            self.second()
            self.third()

d = demo()
d.first()
d.second()
d.third()
```